# Regarding in-app purchase : Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i am using in-app purchase for my quiz app to buy coins.And i have added 2 coins category 100 coins and 500 coins respectively.I have also added 2 SKU.My both coin purchase works well.While i purchase 100 coins and consume.100 coins gets added to app but when i purchase 500 coins once again 100 coins get added and not 500.I really need a helping hand as i am stuck with this for weeks.Here is the consume app purchase code

```
private void update() {
    ArrayList<String> moreSkus = new ArrayList<String>();
    moreSkus.add(SKU);
    moreSkus.add(SKU_500);

    buyHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, moreSkus, new QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {
            if(result.isSuccess()) {
               // SkuDetails details = inv.getSkuDetails(SKU);
                //String price = details.getPrice();

                //TextView tvPrice = (TextView)GameActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.textview_price);
               // tvPrice.setText(price);

                purchase = inv.getPurchase(SKU);
               // purchase = inv.getPurchase(SKU_500);
                purchase=inv.getPurchase(SKU_500);
                if(purchase!=null) {
                 //   buy100coins.setEnabled(false);
                    //coins_one_hundred.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // buy100coins.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    buy100coins.setEnabled(false);
                    buy500coins.setEnabled(false);


                   //boughtcoins.setEnabled(true);
                   //boughtcoins.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    boughtcoins.setEnabled(true);

                } else {
                  //  buy100coins.setEnabled(true);
                    //coins_one_hundred.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // buy100coins.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buy100coins.setEnabled(true);
                    buy500coins.setEnabled(true);

                    //boughtcoins.setEnabled(false);
                    //boughtcoins.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    boughtcoins.setEnabled(false);

                } 

                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Successful got inventory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Error getting inventory!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and button to consume

```
               boughtcoins = (Button) buycoinsdialog.findViewById(R.id.bought_coins);
                        //boughtcoins.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                        boughtcoins.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Helper.playSound(getApplicationContext(), "click");
                                buyHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, new OnConsumeFinishedListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                                        if(result.isSuccess()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Coins consumed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Helper.playSound(getApplicationContext(), "cash");                                      
                                                money += 100;
                                               money_text.setText( "$" + money);

                                            try {
                                                // Small HACK: Give the system some time to realize the consume... without the sleep here,
                                                // you have to press "Update" to see that the item can be bought again... 
                                                Thread.sleep(600);
                                                update();
                                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                                // ignored
                                            }

                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(GameActivity.this, "Error consuming: "+result.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });


                                buycoinsdialog.dismiss();


                            }
                        });
```

Comment: you are adding money += 100; only for both purchaces. check this.

Comment: @Rama i tried changing that to 500 ie if(purchase.getsku().equals(SKU){ } but it doesn't work

Comment: @Rama i am not sure about above code ie within update() method.On how to add second SKU to it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like regardless of what the user selects your increasing the money/coin count by 100 as per this line:

```
money += 100;
```

Where are you handling the 500 coin purchase?

Comment: I tried adding money +=500 but it doesn't work.can you tell me if the above code ie update() method is correct?ie is that the way to add second SKU?

Comment: can you check that please?

Comment: I've used in-app billing once before but I can't remember exactly...but your onConsumeFinished method returns a Purchase object. Does that perhaps have some sort of identifier to let you know which purchase was made? If it does, maybe you can do something like this: if(purchase.code(SKU_500) { money += 500 }; makes sense?

Comment: my doubt is can  use same test package name for both SKU?

Comment: i tried changing first SKU package name different and have added android test package name to second SKU it works ie it adds 500 coins

Comment: Did you try to dissect which purchase was made via the Purchase object?

Comment: Try to debug the code and set a breakpoint to check what purchase.getSKU() returns when you attempt to make a 500 coin purchase.

Comment: yeah just now what i did was i changed first sku package name and used test package for second sku and have added code within                                     public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) { } ie if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU)){money+=100} else if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU)){money+=500 } and when i purchase using 500 button it returns 500 coins where as for 100 coins since i change package name it doesn't

Comment: ie my doubt is protected static final String SKU_500 = "android.test.purchased"; protected static final String SKU = "android.test.purchased";

can it be used for 2 SKU ?

Comment: Okay I see two things wrong with your code that you rjust posted. First, you're checking twice if(purchase.getSku().equals(SKU)) and once doing money += 100 and the second time money +=500. Second thing is that SKU and SKU_500 are equal??? If they are equal then how can you ever compare them???

Comment: SKU and SKU_500 are not equal.I used tutorial from this link https://www.gaffga.de/implementing-in-app-billing-for-android/ for in app billing and there only one SKU added.i need to add second sku to that code used on that website.so if possible can you tell me steps to add second sku to that code?

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed when I did it and although it was a bit confusing, I was able to add two different items for purchasing successfully: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download. Also there is a sample application which was very very helpful: http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample. IAB is the worst experience I've ever had on Android so far, so good luck my friend. Mark my answer correct? :)

Comment: Oh i see.I wish i could choose any answers correct.But I couldn't add second sku as it works some time and it doesn't .can you tell me how to add second sku and if i am successful i will mark answer correct :) .Btw sample application by android developer site is too much confusing.i prefer that link which i posted ;)

Comment: can you tell me how to add second sku for that code?

Comment: I would have to go back into my old code at home. I'll try get back to you tomorrow as I'm at work right now :)

Comment: Ok.Glad to hear.I will be waiting for your reply. :)

Comment: As i need solution badly.My app release been delayed because of this.

Comment: No worries. I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi,i am waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to do as follow

```
 if(purchase.getSKU() == SKU_500){
money += 500;
}else if(purchase.getSKU() == SKU_100){
money += 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener2 
    = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                   Purchase purchase) 
    {
       if (result.isFailure()) {
          // Handle error
          return;
     }else {
if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU1)) {
                 // do things
    }else if(purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU2){}
}

  }
};
```

check this it may help you

Comment: thanks for the above code.As discussed with The Hungry Androider i changed SKU package name and added code within that bought button and it returns 500 coins.but my question is can two android test package be used?

Comment: which ids are you using.Whether test SKUs or your ids?If you are using your custom  ids then you can assign  your interested way.But those ids must not be similar

Comment: I used test sku package name for both SKU ie SKU and SKU_500

Comment: you mean  "android.test.purchase"?

Comment: can you go through this tutorial https://www.gaffga.de/implementing-in-app-billing-for-android/ and tell me how to add second sku to that code?

Answer (score 0):

// on clicking your button call this method

```
 if (mHelper!=null) mHelper.flagEndAsync();
                    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 10001,
                            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try after a few seconds"+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

implement listener as folloew:

```
 IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                        Purchase purchase) 
        {
           if (result.isFailure()) {
              // Handle error
              return;
         }      
         else{

    mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
        }

       }
    };
```

// implement listener  for "mConsumeFinishedListener" as follows:

```
 IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener()
        {
             public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, 
                   IabResult result) 
             {

                if (result.isSuccess()) 
                {                
                      if(purchase.getSKU().equals("android.test.purchase")){
}else if(purchase.getSKU().equals("android.test.cancel")){
}


                } 
            }
        };
```

Comment: you have to implement in this way for consumable items.